# I need a bit of advice with recoding a function loop in delphi

Tags: delphi

Am currently using the code below to generate my userlist in my chat system but I noticed after a while or too many users online the loop becomes very unable and will miss or add fake users so is there any other way of generating same type of info but more stable I was thinking maybe stringlist but have no idea how to add the needed information below.

```
function GetLobbyUsers(const aLobbyID: string): string;
    var
      i: Integer;
      HostID: string;
    begin
      Result := '';
      for i := 0 to (SocketServer.ClientCount -1) do
      begin
        if (CompareText(SocketServer.Client[i].Lobby, aLobbyID) = 0) then
        begin
          HostID := '';
          HostID := IntToStr(Integer(CompareText(SocketServer.Client[i].LobbyOwner, SocketServer.Client[i].Name) = 0));
          //
          SocketServer.Client[i].HasHighLatancy := False;
          SocketServer.Client[i].HasLowLatancy := False;
          SocketServer.Client[i].IsCheckingLatancy := True;
          //
          Result := Result + 'š11œ' + aLobbyID + 'œ'
            + SocketServer.Client[i].Name + 'œ'
            + SocketServer.Client[i].Rank + 'œ'
            + SocketServer.Client[i].IconNumber + 'œ'
            + SocketServer.Client[i].BIconNumber + 'œ'
            + MBoolToStr(SocketServer.Client[i].IsAFK) + 'œ'
            + HostID + 'œ'
            + SocketServer.Client[i].HasTrophy + 'œ'
            + MBoolToStr(SocketServer.Client[i].IsDownloading) + 'œ'
            + MBoolToStr(SocketServer.Client[i].HasHighLatancy) + 'œ'
            + MBoolToStr(SocketServer.Client[i].HasLowLatancy) + 'œ'
            + MBoolToStr(SocketServer.Client[i].IsCheckingLatancy) + 'œ'
            + MBoolToStr(SocketServer.Client[i].IsBlocked) + 'œ';
          end;
       end;
    end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, a sorted TStringList would probably be better, and depending on the version of Delphi there are probably even better alternatives. This code has many issues with style, at least. You should probably post it over on code review. One thing: You set HostID to the success/failure result of CompareText - is that right?

Comment: HostID is just a owner of lobby if its empty it be blank else it show name am using Delphi xe2

Answer (score 0):

Being a chat system and assuming SocketServer.Client is the list of connected users, is it possible that users are connecting and disconnecting while you are still iterating the list of users? If so, then SocketServer.ClientCount could be modified while you are still iterating which would be very bad. This might explain why you get fake users (i.e. disconnected while iterating) or missing users (connected while still iterating). If this is the case, then you might need to lock SocketServer.Client while you are iterating it i.e. prevent adding or removing items from the list. Or maybe create a copy of SocketServer.Client and iterate the copy. Regardless, performance is critical so you need to iterate the list of users very quickly.

For better performance, I would not call SocketServer.Client[i] so many times. Set a reference like `user := SocketServer.Client[i];` then replace all those SocketServer.Client[i] with user.

I also think concatenating one string with all the users seems odd and may affect performance. It seems like you could build a single string on each iteration and add it to a TStringList.

Comment: I was thinking about stringlist my self but I do think problem is with users disconnecting so need to look into that also the client[i] is a index